# thread pool error trapping

Tags: vb.net, threadpool

Checking on a best practice here.

I am calling a ThreadPool to run an Async process, specifically sending an SSL email with an attachment which seems to take a good long while.

This is just test code, I thought I would drop this in a Try Catch just incase something failed. But will the thread ever even come back here? I have tested this closing the web page, the browser, clicking the back button on the page. The email always makes it through.

```
Try
   System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf DoAsyncWork)   '
Catch ex As Exception
   Throw ex
   Exit Sub
 End Try
```

I am not trying to force a failure, yet I guess, but I would like to know how best to trap if the thread fails.

```
Protected Sub DoAsyncWork(ByVal state As Object)   
   Dim oMyObject As New sendSSLemail
   oMyObject.SSL(userName, , strMessageBody, emailAdd, , permFileLocation, , "CodeMsg")
End Sub
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what framework version are you running?

Comment: What is the point of catching an exception, doing nothing with it and then rethrowing it by using `Throw ex` which looses the original exception's stack trace?

Comment: The odds that QUWI throws an exception are zero.  You must deal with it in DoAsyncWork().  That's forever nasty, fire-and-forget is very hard to deal with, exceptions won't let you forget.  Do consider using BackgroundWorker or Task so you can easily marshal a mishap back to the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more convenient way of doing work with the thread pool is to use [`Task.Factory.StartNew(Action)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx). It returns a `Task` object which can be `Await`ed or blocked on with [`Wait`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635(v=vs.110).aspx).

Once the task completes, the `Exception` property of the `Task` can be used to determine whether an exception was thrown and unhandled by the task's subroutine. (If it's not `Nothing`, then the `InnerException` property has the real exception that was thrown.)

```
Dim task = Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf WorkFunction)
' do stuff that doesn't depend on WorkFunction having completed
task.Wait()
If task.Exception IsNot Nothing Then Throw task.Exception.InnerException
```

After a `Throw`, the sub is exited anyway (the call stack is unwound looking for a `Catch`), so the `Exit Sub` statement does nothing. Wrapping a `QueueUserWorkItem` call in a try block also does nothing, because any exception would occur on the other thread. You would only get exceptions thrown immediately by `QueueUserWorkItem`, which off the top of my head only includes complaints about the delegate being `Nothing`.

Asynchronous tasks can also return values. For more information on that, see [the `TaskFactory` methods that return a `Func(Of Task)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321455(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I wish I could give you more points. this is the exact solution I needed.